# Why is the POST callback function not working

Tags: jquery, post

I am trying to perform the following [fadeIn/fadeOut action](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/01/effect-delay-trick) within the jQuery $.post function.

```
$.post('Scenario/SaveScenario', function (data) {
    $('<div class="save-alert">The current scenario has been saved.</div>')
    .insertAfter($('.buttons'))
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 2000)
    .fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

However, this does not work and (apparently) nothing happens. (I put a breakpoint inside the function within Firebug and it is never reached.) The post is happening successfully as the scenario is being put into my database. I don't believe that is the problem.

I tested it out by just adding it as a click event on the submit button and that did work.

```
$(function () {
    $('#SaveScenario').click(function () {
        $('<div class="save-alert">The current scenario has been saved.</div>')
        .insertAfter($('.buttons'))
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 2000)
        .fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Any theories about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the request is coming back successfully?  What does the response look like in Firebug, Chrome or Fiddler?

Comment: @Nick - Spot on.  Haha...see my response to Vivin. I earned my noob point for the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()  method.

So the post might be hitting the server fine and going through, but there might be some sort of error when the post comes back to jQuery (maybe an unexpected form of data) or maybe a general sort of error on the way back (a bad response code)? Try sending making your request with `jQuery.ajax` and provide it an `error` handler to see if some sort of error is happening. For example, if you used `ajaxSetup` and set your `dataType` to `json` and you didn't return valid JSON from the server, jQuery will die with a parse error.

What do you get when you simply hit `http://your.site.com/Scenario/SaveScenario`?

Comment: Wow...I win noob points for what I did.  I was returning View() in the SaveScenario action. Therefore, I was getting a 500 from the SaveScenario (I didn't realize that the database would still get the commit, interestingly enough). So, now I redirect back to the input page and things work. /sigh  Some days...

Comment: @Jason no worries - I suspected it was something like that (which is why I mentioned "bad response code") :)

Comment: +1 Cause my problem solved after removing 'json' from the post call because I was not returning the json. Saved my lots of time :)

Comment: +1. My issue was similar to Pawan's, except that in my PHP file I set the content-type to `application/json` and jQuery was not expecting a JSON file so it was silently failing. All along I thought it was an issue with the jQuery until I read this answer ("maybe an unexpected form of data"). Thanks!